# Pop-Up Canvas/Panel Not Blocking Raycast to Buttons/UI Below

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, raycasting

I'm trying to create a pop-up window that will overlay on top of the current canvas and block all interaction with it. Everything I read says to use Canvas Group(s) and/or Graphic Raycaster, but I can't find the magic combination to make that work.

Canvas O is a Screen-Space overlay for typical buttons.
Canvas K is a World-Space canvas for my current UI stuff that I can pan around and whatnot.
Canvas P is my popup which is also an overlay and which I want to block all interaction with both O and K "behind" it. I've put a Canvas group on all 3, I've put a Graphic Raycaster on P, I've selected "Blocks Raycasts" in the Canvas Group of P as well as setting the "Blocking Objects" and "Blocking Mask" to All and Everything. I've put colliders on, and I've made the canvases different Sort Orders for layering. I'm out of ideas. Why won't it block??

Comment: Do you have tried to play with layers?

Comment: I just tried changing it to layer 10: Overlay. Didn't do anything different :-\

Answer (score 0):

Canvas UI objects are drawn in descending order (so that the lowest object under the canvas in the inspector is drawn last and is in front of everything else).

Like this:

- Canvas

  - Text1
  - Text2 (drawn after Text1)
  - OverlayImage (drawn after Text1 and Text2, blocking raycasts)

If you add an image UI object to a canvas, drag it to be the lowest object under that canvas in the inspector like in the example above, then expand it so that it takes up the entire canvas, and set the anchors (which control resizing) to expand based on the width and height of the window, that image should always cover the entire canvas. As long as it stays as the lowest GameObject in the inspector hierarchy, it should block events underneath that on that canvas.

I'm not sure about one canvas blocking events on other canvases in the scene, but I would add OverlayImages on all of the canvases, and control whether the OverlayImages are enabled or disabled from canvas P in your example.

Comment: So it may be that the answer is that it can't be done to have one Canvas block another? For now I just made a workaround to deactivate the other canvases when the popup is open. Kinda annoying though!